# Resolving ambiguity in simple Instaparse grammar

Tags: clojure, grammar, instaparse

[Also posted on the [Instaparse mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/instaparse), but posted here as well since I'm guessing this is a fairly general problem]

Consider the grammar

```
 D = (B|S)*
 S = 'S' B*
 B = 'B'
```

(This is [Instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse)'s version of BNF...)

B can occur by itself, or after S; if the latter, it should be considered part of the, er, S expression (no pun intended).

Example:

```
(-> "D = (B|S)*
     S = 'S' B*
     B = 'B'"
    parser
    (parses "BSBB"))

;;=>
([:D [:B "B"] [:S "S"] [:B "B"] [:B "B"]]
 [:D [:B "B"] [:S "S" [:B "B"] [:B "B"]]]    ;; <------
 [:D [:B "B"] [:S "S" [:B "B"]] [:B "B"]])
```

I'd like only the second result to match -- so that B gets included inside S when possible, and to remove the other options.  What needs to be done to my parser to make this change?

More example expressions shown in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/eigenhombre/868cfdc02e622caae746).

Comment: Aren't you just trying to recognize `'B'* ('S' 'B'*)*`? That's completely unambiguous, and easy to write in BNF.

Comment: @rici - indeed, that also works -- thanks!  My question is actually a simplified version of a more complex grammar, for which the negative lookahead is indeed needed AFAICT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead to postulate that matches of `S` must not be followed by valid `B`s:

```
(-> "

D = (B|S)*
S = 'S' B* !B
B = 'B'

"
insta/parser
(insta/parses "BSBB"))
;= ([:D [:B "B"] [:S "S" [:B "B"] [:B "B"]]])
```

This works for all the examples in (the current version of) your gist as well.